# Procedure or function 'spCategory1' expects parameter '@Cat1ID', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two dropdownlists for category and subcategory.So when i change the category,it should populate the subcategory with a desired options depending upon the selection.So obviously i have two tables,one for category and another for subcategory and they are properly linked.Here are the two tables:

```
      create table tblCategory
      (
     CatId int primary key identity,
     Category nvarchar(50)
       )
```

and

```
      create table tblSubCategory
      (
      SubId int primary key identity,
      SubCategory nvarchar(50),
      CatId int
       )
```

I have a stored procedure:

```
      create proc spCategory1
      @Cat1ID int
      as
      begin
      select * from tblSubCategory where CatId=@Cat1ID
      end
```

The code-behind:

```
      protected void ddlCat1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Cat1ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCat1.SelectedValue);
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IndiaLystConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCategory1", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CatId",@Cat1ID);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlSCat1.DataSource = ds;
        ddlSCat1.DataTextField = "SubCategory";
        ddlSCat1.DataValueField = "SubId";
        ddlSCat1.DataBind();
    }
    ddlSCat1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}
```

Howvever,this throws an error.I have tested the stored procedure by using:

```
     Execute spCategory1 '1'
```

and it works fine.I have tried everything but nothing seems to be working.Help.

Comment: have you tried : `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat1ID", Cat1ID);`?

Comment: @har07 - Yes.Throws the same exception.

Comment: Is Cat1ID null ? Did you debug to the line of error to see what Cat1ID actually contains ? And this line is wrong :         'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CatId",@Cat1ID)'; have to be :         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatId",Cat1ID);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies here :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CatId",@Cat1ID);
```

First of all the way you send parameter is wrong. It should be :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatId",Cat1ID);
```

Second thing the parameter name in your store procedure is `@Cat1ID int` but you are sending `@CatId`
remember **the parameter name should be same as that of the store procedure**, something like this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat1ID",Cat1ID);
```

Correct your code and let me know if that works.